# Deploying authenticated cloud function using firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to uncheck "Allow unauthenticated invocations" in my newly created cloud function. I can do it from console. But i want it to be done via command prompt(firebase deploy). I am looking  out for some field/attribute which i can add while deploying the cloud function. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: It's not possible today.  Please file a feature request with Firebase support.  You can also use gcloud to deploy your functions, but you will not be able to use the firebase-functions module.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at the time of writing, the public invocation policy is hard coded into the `firebase-tools` CLI.

The code in question can be found in [`firebase-tools/src/deploy/functions/release.js`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/a875be076ca4c2c4e3663723e9b0337a994898ab/src/deploy/functions/release.js#L26-L34).